# SQL Server Create Custom Counter for Before Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create my custom counter for creating Primary Keys. I did manage to do in PL/SQL.

```
create or replace trigger company_before_insert
  Before insert
  on egenc.company_table REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
  begin
    select 'CM' || lpad(company_seg.nextval,5,0)
    into :new.companyid
    from dual;
  end;
```

This piece of code creates a trigger which creates custom primary key for company_table. company_seg is my custom counter. Whenever I insert a row it creates a Primary Key like:CM00001
How can I create a custom counter in SQL Server for creating varchar primary keys?

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql server I would use an `identity` column and a persisted computed column based on it's value. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
(
    Sample_Id smallint identity(1,1), 
    Sample_Computed as 'CM' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Sample_Id as varchar(5)), 5) PERSISTED 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Sample PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Testing - insert 3 records:

```
INSERT INTO Sample DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO Sample DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO Sample DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Testing - Select:

```
SELECT *
FROM  Sample
```

Results:

```
Sample_Id   Sample_Computed
1           CM00001
2           CM00002
3           CM00003
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/BBK95013)

However, please note that creating such a primary key means you can only have 99999 records in your table. For more records you need more digits.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Servers use transact sql or t-sql ----- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql 
Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql

Learn this and apply same logic as in PL SQL.

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome. Please included essential parts from the link that are relevant to the question.